# Javascript onload callback for "type" or "rel", 'text/plain' on script or link tag

Tags: javascript

Why isn't onload fired for script type="text/plain" ? loadPlain below doesn't fire the callback, but loadScript does.

I expected this to work... should it not?

```
    loadPlain("http://localhost/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", function(element) {
            alert(1);
            alert(element.innerHTML);
    }, undefined, {})

    function loadPlain(path, callback, errorCallback, options) {
            var element = document.createElement('script');
            element.setAttribute("type", 'text/plain');
            element.setAttribute("src", path);

            return loadBase(element, callback, errorCallback, options);
    }

    function loadScript(path, callback, errorCallback, options) {
            var element = document.createElement('script');
            element.setAttribute("type", 'text/javascript');
            element.setAttribute("src", path);

            return loadBase(element, callback, errorCallback, options);
    }


    function loadBase(element, callback, errorCallback, options) {
            element.loaded = false;

            if (element.readyState){  // IE
                    element.onreadystatechange = function(){
                            if (element.readyState == "loaded" || element.readyState == "complete"){
                                    element.onreadystatechange = null;

                                    loadBaseOnload(element, callback);
                            }
                    };
            } else {                 // Others
                    element.onload = function() {
                            loadBaseOnload(element, callback);
                    };
            }

            element.onerror = function() {
                    errorCallback && errorCallback(element);
            };

            (options.elementAppendTo || document.head || loadBase.head || (loadBase.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]) || document.body).appendChild(element);

            return element;
    }

    function loadBaseOnload(element, callback) {
            if (element.loaded != true) {
                    element.loaded = true;
                    if ( callback ) callback(element);
            }
    }
```

Please note that I know about XMLHttpRequest, but thats not the question :)

Comment: How are you using your function loadPlain? I ask because it seems similar in style to your function loadScript, so it may be in the way you're using it that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WHATWG (the organization who specifies browser behavior, alongside the W3C) has a [list of known script MIME types](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#scriptingLanguages) and some blacklisted MIME types that must not be treated as scripting languages:

> The following lists the MIME type strings that user agents must recognize, and the languages to which they refer:
>
> - `"application/ecmascript"`
> - `"application/javascript"`
> - `"application/x-ecmascript"`
> - ...
>
> The following MIME types (with or without parameters) must not be interpreted as scripting languages:
>
> - `"text/plain"`
> - `"text/xml"`
> - `"application/octet-stream"`
> - `"application/xml"`
>
> Note: These types are explicitly listed here because they are poorly-defined types that are nonetheless likely to be used as formats for data blocks, and it would be problematic if they were suddenly to be interpreted as script by a user agent.

What the WHATWG spec calls "data blocks" here are **non-scripts** enclosed in `<script>` tags:

> In this example, two script elements are used. One embeds an external script, and the other includes some data.

```
<script src="game-engine.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-game-map">`
........U.........e
o............A....e
.....A.....AAA....e
.A..AAA...AAAAA...e
</script>
```

The components of the WHATWG spec that specify `load` events for `<script>` tags explicitly state that they fire for *scripts* referred to by `<script>` tags, not to non-script data blocks. A `<script>` element is a data block if its `type` is not recognized as a MIME type corresponding to a scripting language supported by the browser. This means that blacklisted types like `text/plain` will never be recognized as scripts, whereas type values in neither the must-support nor must-not-support list, like `application/dart` (for Google's Dart language) might be supported by some browsers.

Furthermore, including a non-script `type` alongside a `src` is not spec-compliant. Data blocks are legal only when specified inline:

> When used to include data blocks (as opposed to scripts), the **data must be embedded inline**, the format of the data must be given using the `type` attribute, the **`src` attribute must not be specified**, and the contents of the script element must conform to the requirements defined for the format used.

Comment: One would expect the onload to fire anyways. But I guess that is not possible. Not even link type stylesheet fires an onload either. I guess I will have to use xmlhttprequest for this one...

Answer (score 1):

If you specify your script as "text/plain" the browser wont do anything with it.

You must specify it as "script/javascript" to have it execute as JavaScript.

Comment: But I just want the onload to fire, I don't need it to execute the javacript, just want to know when it is loaded ...

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me .. why would you load a resource and then do nothing with it?

Comment: I am not loading it as javascript, I just want the contents of it. I already have logic for loading via adding a script, so I figured I would be able to use the same stuff, and read the innerhtml ( not cross domain ) later on

Comment: You want to get the source of a JavaScript file that you're interpreting as plain-text but are still importing to a `script` node? That doesn't make sense :P Why not just do an AJAX call to the script? Much simpler.

Comment: @MoJS Browsers ignore `<script>` tags with a content-type they don't know about.

Comment: It happens to be a javascript file in the example, but can be any file  type. It is not much simples if it would just have worked to change the type from what I already have..

Comment: @EtienneMiret Thanks, thats weird though .. i expexted the onload to fire when the file has finished loading

Comment: @MoJS it's very likely the browser will actually throw a warning in the console complaining about the content-type.

Comment: I think the text/plain is allowed as type, is it not?

Comment: The link for css doesn't fire any onload event either ... I wonder how lesscss.js does this. I guess they might be listening for new inserted elements

Comment: If you look at the source code of less.js you'll see that they use xhr to get the less source code, transform it to CSS client side and add that to the DOM. So there is no need for an onload on the `style` element.